# Clipping lines that enter circle (using overleaf)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to remove a line (from an ellipse) when it crosses into the circle, but cant seem to get it to work:(

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[ball color = gray!100, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
  \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$r$} (2,0);
  \def \firstellipse {(-1.5,0) ellipse (2 and 4)} 
  \draw[dashed] \firstellipse
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So to clarify, i want to remove the parts of the ellipsis that is within the borders of the circle!

Answer (score 1):

Well you could:

- use a `\clip` just before the ellipse but this requires extra code, or better...
- remove the `opacity = 0.4` from the ellipse and change the color command (I assume you just want it lighter), from `gray!100`<sup>1</sup> to `gray!10`, for example.

  Also, move the `ellipse` so it appears before the `ball` shape.

In the end it should be like this:

```
\draw[dashed] \firstellipse; % <-- also the semicolon was missing in your code
\shade[ball color = gray!10] (0,0) circle (2cm);
```

and the result is

[image]

<sup>**1:** By the way, `gray!100` gives the same output as just `gray`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [inverted clip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/227987). Notice that instead of `\def` you can use `insert path` to store a path in a macro or key.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={overlay,insert path={[reset cm]
      (-16383.99999pt,-16383.99999pt) rectangle
      (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={insert path={(0,0) circle[radius=2]}},
    e/.style={insert path={(-1.5,0) circle[x radius=2,y radius=4]}}]
  \draw[ball color = gray!100,fill opacity = 0.4,c];
  \draw (-2,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius=2,y radius=0.6];
  \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,x radius=2,y radius=0.6];
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$r$} (2,0);
  \clip[c,reverseclip];
  \draw[overlay=false,dashed,e];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]